# How to anticipate a software future where ARM (potentially) replaces x86 in server and PCs?

Tags: architecture, development-process, cpu, experience, arm

With the introduction of Apple M1 processor, ARM has stood up to be a capable competitor and an alternative to x86 processors. We can foresee a future where ARM captures considerable market share of x86 in the server space. That means we will be writing software that works and is optimised for ARM.

Such a change would definitely affect developers who deal with low level code(device drivers, compilers, os and os kernels, etc) that requires knowledge and expertise of underlying cpu architecture.

But would such a technology shift affect "general" developers too?  I mean developers who are mostly involved in implementing business logic using high level languages such as Python, Javascript, Java, C#, etc. Those languages and their implementations usually take care of running the same piece of code on different os and cpu architectures and developers just have to focus on implementing the requirements.

If yes, how would it affect the "general" devs and what would change in the development work? How can we prepare for such a change?  Will some programming languages become preferable over others? Should we consider cross-platform frameworks?

Comment: I tried to reword slightly your question, removing the personal stuff, and underlining more the technical challenges rather than the skill-development aspects.  The latter is out of scope here (career and education),  but the impact on techniques and  development processes are fully legitimate imho.  I hope you agree with the change, if not you can still revert it :-)

Comment: (Regarding byte order / endianness) So far, for mainstream uses (non-legacy; non-hobbyist), including personal, PC and mobile, commercial, server-side uses, it is not necessary to consider big-endianness machine architecture, as the above-mentioned uses are almost exclusively little-endian.

Comment: Regarding choice of programming languages and technology stacks: one should feel assured that the change from x86 to ARM should not cause disruptions to most programmers. Except components that are written in C and C++ (and, occasionally, code that is written in assembly language, such as libjpeg-turbo, which must provide handwritten assemblies for each of the CPU architectures). Software that incorporates third-party modules written in C and C++ will need to be prepared.

Comment: For maintainers of software, it is important to have a full understanding of all dependencies of your software stack, e.g. what "libraries" your software depends on, and what secondary libraries do they depend on etc. It is necessary for someone in your team to have a top-to-bottom understanding of your entire software stack.

Comment: If your software depend on modules that are written in C or C++, or if they are only available in binary form (compiled), the most important thing is to ensure access to their source code. Porting these to a different architecture always require their original source code. Without their original source code, there can be a lot of difficulty. In addition to their source code, it is necessary to maintain a working build (compilation) system for any components written in C / C++.

Comment: @Christophe I totally agree with your edits. I did consider the career and education aspect of the question but the question was so specific to software development I believed this was the right forum. I really appreciate the time and effort you have put to edit and answer the question instead of just downvoting impatiently.

Comment: Software development tools provided by Microsoft and Apple already tried to make cross-platform (multi-platform) development as smooth as possible.

Comment: In MacOS, there is some software that gets compiled to x86 code at runtime (web browsers for example). On a Mac with ARM processor that kind of code is translated to ARM code by the OS. And apps that are compiled to x86 will be translated at the first launch.

Comment: Really affected is not “low level code” but assembler code.

Comment: Really affected is (1) code written with machine-specific and architecture-specific assumptions; these require a modification or a rewrite, depending on how specific the code is; (2) code that is compiled down to a machine-specific or architecture-specific file format (e.g. shared binary objects); these may not require code changes, but will require a recompile.

Comment: see [On discussions and why they don't make good questions](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6742/31260)

Comment: @gnat The single answer below and the above comments, all seem to share a similar set of solutions. Isn't that different from a discussion where you have different opinionated solutions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quite simple: write portable code in a high-level, multi-platform language, without making assumptions about endianness, or size of integers, and CPU architecture.  Just check if your favourite language supports the new platform.

It’s **not a new situation**: 30 years ago the CPU landscape was very diverse. There was x86, [M68K](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motorola_68000_series), [PowerPC](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/PowerPC), [Sparc](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/SPARC) and several others. You had to trust your OS, your compilers and your libraries.  It’s far more challenging to have a consistent multi-platform user-interface across many systems, than supporting multiple processors (provided you kept portability in mind).

One challenge is the communication between processes which could use different CPU architectures. Binary data makes a lot of assumptions about the CPU and requires some extra caution. But in reality, this  challenge exists already today if you use multi-language development.

Another challenge  will be to package and distribute multi-target code. While this may impact the toolchain, build, test (multiple automated tests for each targeted platform required) and distribution process, this will not fundamentally impact the way software is developed. The best preparation here is probably to familiarize yourself with multi-target open source projects.

Comment: Thanks for your response, it covers all the points I was looking for.